# What is the effect of axis rotation on functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I haven't studied multivariable calculus yet but I have a question that bothers me. Let $F$ be a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Imagine that we rotate the co-ordinate axis by an angle $\theta$. I think the shape of the function should change. How should this function change if we make a rotation of the co-ordinate axis by some angle?

Comment: Do you mean to rotate in the plane of inputs $R^2$? If so this will only rotate the entire graph of $F$. If you want to rotate the entire $R^3$ in which the graph lies, the rotation may not even give the graph of a function.

Comment: Yes, I mean to rotate the domain . How can we express the new function in terms of the old function and the angle $\theta$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $F : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be the given function, and let $G_{\theta} : \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be rotation by $\theta$, then you want to consider the function $F\circ G_{\theta}$. Note that $G_{\theta}$ is a linear transformation and its standard matrix is a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) so we obtain

$$G_{\theta}\left(\left[\begin{array}\ x\\ y\end{array}\right]\right) = \left[\begin{array}\ \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}\ x\\ y\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}\ x\cos\theta - y\sin\theta\\ x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta\end{array}\right].$$

Therefore,

$$(F\circ G_{\theta})(x, y) = F(G_{\theta}(x, y)) = F(x\cos\theta - y\sin\theta, x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta).$$

Note that the graph of $F\circ G_{\theta}$ is just the graph of $F$ rotated around the $z$-axis by $\theta$.